# $\frac{2.00013579}{1.00013579^2+2.00013579}$ > $\frac{2.0002468}{1.0002468^2 + 2.0002468}$?

Tags: calculus, inequality

> Determine which one of the following two numbers is greater: $\frac{2.00013579}{1.00013579^2+2.00013579}$ or $\frac{2.0002468}{1.0002468^2 + 2.0002468}$.

---

How can I do this without a calculator? I tried comparing the numerator to the numerator, and the denominator to the denominator, but that did not work. I tried seeing whether the squares would change very little since they were really close to $1$, but I couldn't form any solid reasoning.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** let $2.00013579=x,2.0002468=y$,$x,y> 2$

Also notice that $$f(x)=\frac{x}{{(x-1)}^2+x}=\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x}-1}$$ is decreasing for $x\ge 1$

> As $x<y$:$$\frac{x}{{(x-1)}^2+x}>\frac{y}{{(y-1)}^2+y}$$

Comment: Thank you! :) This helped a lot.

Comment: @MikeSmith you are welcome!

Comment: you could say it's decreasing on $[1, \infty)$.

Comment: @orangeskid ofcourse i was thinking of that but it does not matter here ,does it?

Comment: @orangeskid i have included your suggestion

Comment: I guess so... once you have the nice expression for $f(x)$ it's all clear